# How to use Refunds and Adjustments via SDK (QBFC)?

Tags: qbfc

I have been integrating my application with QuickBooks using the SDK QBFC.  I have invoices working successfully.  The issue I have come across and am struggling to find recources for is with credits.  When sending the request to create an invoice with a negative value I get this message:

"Transaction amount must be positive."

I have tried using using the quantity as a negative and rate hoping it would work out the amount as a negative but then I got this:

"You can't use negative rates on inventory items, use neg quantity instead"

So, I have come to the realization that I need to use the Refunds and Adjustments in QuickBooks and cannot find any examples to follow.

Comment: I have worked this out.  Using the same structure you would to create the request for an invoice but replace:

Dim invAdd As IInvoiceAdd
Set invAdd = msgSetRq.AppendInvoiceAddRq

With:

Dim refundAdd As ICreditMemoAdd
Set refundAdd = msgSetRq.AppendCreditMemoAddRq

Answer (score 2):

I have worked this out.  Using the same structure you would to create the request for an invoice but replace:

Dim invAdd As IInvoiceAdd
Set invAdd = msgSetRq.AppendInvoiceAddRq

With:

Dim refundAdd As ICreditMemoAdd
Set refundAdd = msgSetRq.AppendCreditMemoAddRq

Comment: You also need to convert negative lineitems into positive line-items, since a negative invoice maps to a positive credit.